# Configuration of database.yml in rails apllication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

For setting up the Development, Test and Production environment , the syntax is up to mark but when my line alignment of each environment variable varies , its giving error. why? Such a brain storming game is playing with the coding in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 2):

This is not because of ROR but [`YAML`](https://learn.getgrav.org/advanced/yaml)

```
YAML files should end in .yaml whenever possible.
YAML is case sensitive.
YAML does not allow the use of tabs. Spaces are used instead as tabs are not universally supported.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

default: &default 
  adapter: mysql2 
  encoding: utf8 
  pool: 5 
  username: root 
  password: "password" 
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock 

development: 
  <<: *default 
  database: exaple_development 

test: 
  <<: *default 
  database: exaple_test 

production: 
  <<: *default 
  database: exaple_production